# Hive MAP isn't reading input correctly

Tags: hive, mahout

I am trying create a table on this mahout recommender system output data on s3.

```
703209355938578 [18519:1.5216354,18468:1.5127649,17962:1.5094717,18317:1.5075916]
828667482548563 [18070:1.0,18641:1.0,18632:1.0,18770:1.0,17814:1.0,18095:1.0]
1705358040772485 [18783:1.0,17944:1.0,18632:1.0,18770:1.0,18914:1.0,18386:1.0]
```

with this schema,

```
CREATE external table user_ad_reco (
userid bigint,
reco MAP<bigint , double>)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
COLLECTION ITEMS TERMINATED BY ','
MAP KEYS TERMINATED BY ':'
LOCATION
's3://xxxxx/data/RS/output/m05/';
```

but while I am reading data back with hive,

hive >

```
select * from user_ad_reco limit 10;
```

It is giving output like this

```
703209355938578 {18519:1.5216354,18468:1.5127649,17962:null}
828667482548563 {18070:1.0,18641:1.0,18632:1.0,18770:1.0,17814:null}
1705358040772485 {18783:1.0,17944:1.0,18632:1.0,18770:1.0,18914:null}
```

So, last key:value of map input is missing in output with null in last output pair :(.

Can anyone help regarding this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reason for nulls :

- input data format with brackets gives null, cause of brackets the row
  format in not being properly read , the last map entry **1.5075916**
  is being read as **1.5075916]**, so it's giving null due to data type
  mismatch.

703209355938578 **[** 18519:1.5216354,18468:1.5127649,17962:1.5094717,18317:1.5075916 **]**

- input data format without brackets works clean : (tested)

703209355938578  18519:1.5216354,18468:1.5127649,17962:1.5094717,18317:1.5075916

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @ramisetty, I have done it in some indirect way, first got rid of two brackets [,] out of the map string, then create schema on string without brackets that.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE  user_ad_reco_serde (
userid STRING,
reco_map STRING
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.RegexSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES  (
"input.regex" = "([0-9]+)\\s\\[([^]]+)]"
)
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION
's3://xxxxxx/data/RS/output/6m/2014-01-2014-05/';  

CREATE external table user_ad_reco_plain(
userid bigint,
reco string)
LOCATION
's3://xxxxx/data/RS/output/6m_plain/2014-01-2014-05/';

CREATE external table user_ad_reco (
userid bigint,
reco MAP<bigint , double>)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\001'
COLLECTION ITEMS TERMINATED BY ','
MAP KEYS TERMINATED BY ':'
LOCATION
's3://xxxxxx/data/RS/output/6m_plain/2014-01-2014-05/';
```

There might be some simpler way.